# BoneCP connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, datanucleus, bonecp

I'm integrating DataNucleus with BoneCP-0.8.0-rc2 and I'm getting this exception, randomly:

```
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:421)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:230)
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014517/bonecp-connection-timeout), I have set

- datanucleus.connectionPool.maxConnectionAgeInSeconds = 170 (seconds)

Other properties that I use:

- datanucleus.connectionPool.minPoolSize=0
- datanucleus.connectionPool.maxPoolSize=8

The local MySQL server where I tested this property has wait_timeout=28800 (seconds).

Since I added this new property, I'm getting the above exception more often than before.

Since the exception doesn't explicitly specify that the connection is closed by the driver, I assume it was closed by the connection manager.

Do you have any other clue what might cause this exception?

Comment: You should be using the idleConnection and friends and let the pool close off connections when not in need rather than maxConnectionAge

Comment: Seems that reverting to boneCP 0.7.1, this exception is not thrown any more. The problem is not I get `WARN  [com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition] - BoneCP detected an unclosed connection and will now attempt to close it for you. You should be closing this connection in your application - enable connectionWatch for additional debugging assistance.
ERROR [com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition] - Error while closing off internal db connection
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.`